# Load csv into a specific slice of an numpy array

Tags: csv, numpy

I have bunch of CSV files that contain array data in text format. I need to make a big `numpy` array out of them. I would prefer not to ingest CSV but that is not in my control.

The way I have been doing this is to use `loadtxt()` to construct a `numpy` array from each of these CSV files and then construct the larger array by concatenating these smaller arrays.  This turns out to be the bottle neck.

Ideally I would like an API that takes an array slice and loads the CSV data in place. Are there `numpy`, `scipy` or some other module/package that does this, or do I have to roll my own.

Comment: In what sense is the concatenate a bottleneck? Do timings show that it takes longer than the repeated `loadtxt`? Have you looked at the internals of `loadtxt`?

Comment: Looked at the internals, yes. I am doing repeated loadtxt anyways. Was looking at ways to avoid one set of copies. More details in the comments section of your helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `loadtxt` just has to be an iterable over lines of text. Open all the files at once and chain them together with an `itertools.chain`, or better yet, define a generator function to open each file in turn and yield all of its lines:

```
filenames = ["foo.csv", "bar.csv"]

def all_files():
    for fn in filenames:
        with open(fn) as f:
            for line in f:
                yield line

my_array = numpy.loadtxt(all_files(), delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Excellent! I didn't know loadtxt could take an iterator. So was mulling over using Fileinput or writing my own loadtxt with an out= parameter where I could pass the destimation slice.

Answer (score 1):

`np.loadtxt` reads your file (or other source) line by line.  It splits the line and converts the strings, and collects everything as a list of tuples.  It's only at the end that it passes this to `np.array` (with dtype).

I suspect that you are collecting these arrays in a list, and then passing that to `np.concatenate`.  That concatenate action should be pretty fast.  I'd expect the multiple `loadtxt` calls to be slower.

I don't know if `codewarriors` approach, of passing multiple files to one `loadtxt` would be faster or not.  It is still reading the data line by line, and collecting it into a list - one big list for all the files.  Then a final `np.array` construction.  If there are header/trailer lines in each file, that `all_files` generator would have to deal with those.

If you know the size of each csv file, you could construct a large empty array, and insert each `loadtxt` result into that.

e.g.

```
N = `number of files`
# each with M rows, L columns
BigMat = np.empty((N,M,L))
for i in range(N):
    arr = np.loadtxt(filenames[i], ...)
    BigMat[i,:,:] = arr
```

Other SO questions have shown that `concatente` and this `for i...; M[i...]=` approach have about the same speed.

Another approach would be to fill `BigMat` line by line.  I believe the `Python` `csv` reader will give you the file line by line, split into fields.  You'd have to do your own conversion to float/int, etc.  It doesn't sound like it would be faster.

```
BigMat[i,j...] = [float(i) for i in fcsv.reader(lines)]
```

A final option is to use `pandas` faster csv loader.

---

Timing tests; different ways of producing a `(m,n)` array from a list of `n` integers.  The list simulates the result of parsing one line from a file.

```
def foo1(x,m):
    # fill in an array with list
    M = np.empty((m,len(x)),int)
    for i in range(m):
        M[i,:] = x
    return M

def foo2(x,m):
    # fill in array - convert list to array first
    M = np.empty((m,len(x)),int)
    for i in range(m):
        M[i,:] = np.array(x)
    return M

def foo3(x,m):
    # append lists; create array
    L = []
    for i in range(m):
        L.append(x)
    M = np.array(L)
    return M

def foo4(x,m):
    # append arrays; vstack
    L = []
    for i in range(m):
        L.append(np.array(x))
    M = np.vstack(L)
    return M

def foo5(x,m):
    # append 2d array; concatente
    L = []
    for i in range(m):
        L.append(np.array([x]))
    M = np.concatenate(L,axis=0)
    return M


In [308]: timeit foo1(range(100),1000)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.8 ms per loop

In [309]: timeit foo2(range(100),1000)
10 loops, best of 3: 27.8 ms per loop

In [310]: timeit foo3(range(100),1000)
100 loops, best of 3: 18.6 ms per loop

In [311]: timeit foo4(range(100),1000)
10 loops, best of 3: 29.6 ms per loop

In [312]: timeit foo5(range(100),1000)
10 loops, best of 3: 24 ms per loop
```

Appending lists, and constructing an array just once has modest time advantages over the others.  This is closest to `codewarriors` solution.  I could refine the tests by working with groups of rows, to better simulate working with multiple files.

The copying from disk to memory, followed by conversion from list of strings to list of numbers is unavoidable.  Those numbers have to be copied at least one more time to put them into a contiguous block of memory.  Avoiding one or two intermediate copies doesn't seem to make a big difference.

I tried variations that created `(m,n,l)` arrays, ie. m files, with n rows, l columns.  The `foo2` style - inserting (n,l) size arrays into M was marginally better.  And that's ignoring the time that `loadtxt` spends opening and reading files.

Comment: You described my set up more or less accurately,  I save some memory by generating the small arrays in a generator expression. I think the inefficiency comes from copying twice. From disk to small arrays and then from the small array to the concated result.

Comment: I tried some timings, and don't get much variation.